# How to make the android LayoutInflater use my Custom Resources

Tags: java, android, android-resources, layout-inflater

I have defined a custom class:

`public class CustomResource extends Resources {}`

in order to load custom external colors at runtime. This is working well in the Java code when using `getResources().getColor()`.

When loading an XML layout via `setContentView()`, which contains references to colors, then `getColor()` of the CustomResources is never called when inflating XML resources.

I already overrode `getResources` and `getSystemService` in the context but `getResources().getColor()` simply does not get called by the View constructors when they resolve XML attributes.

It's because `obtainStyledAttributes()` from `Resource.Theme` is called from within the constructors of Widgets.

I now have no idea what I have to additionally overwrite.

Example: layout.xml contains a reference to drawable/button.xml, button.xml contains a reference to colors/somecolor.

I now need the call from - for example -  a `TextView` constructor (the inflater creates a TextView by calling the constructor with the xml attributes as parameters) which then calls  `obtainStyledAttributes()` to use my resources class for resolving colors rather than the `TypedArray` magic that is currently happening in `obtainStyledAttributes()`.

Comment: what do you use when creating a LayoutInflater?

Comment: I don't create it myself I use setContentView() in Activity for instance. And the layout is of courcse compiled into the app. But I want my Resources class to be used by whatever Inflaters are behind setContentView. But calling/creating an own LayoutInflater would be ok as well. I just couldn't find any examples how to do that instead of setContentView.

Comment: so extend LayoutInflater and pass in the ctor the custom Context that overrides getResources, or even better pass it to static "from()" method

Comment: This is not possible according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33693516/332798

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. I have code for this here.

https://github.com/slightfoot/android-edge-effect-override/blob/master/EdgeEffectOverride.java

Comment: Thanks, but I think I don't get it. When I call `createContextWrapper()` then I get a Wrapper, but what to do with it?

Comment: Use it like this.

`setContentView(LayoutInflater.from(createContextWrapper(xyz)).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null, false));`

Comment: Ahh, thanks, that was the missing piece, understood. So I could just use `LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate()` in an activity already overwriting `getResources()`, correct?

Comment: Ok this is not working: Now my Custom resource gets all calls for resolving system colors BUT no calls for my own colors. It seems the inflater doesn't even bother to call getResources() for colors defined in an application colors.xml. I don't understand why...

Comment: Did you create a ContextWrapper with an overridden getResources()? Check line 128 of the code mentioned above. You might want to try and override getSystemService in your activity like 150 in my example.

Comment: I don't use a ContextWrapper but override getResources and getSystemService directly in my activity. I can see that for instance `LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);`is using my own inflater which I created with LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).cloneInContext(this); in my activity. BUT this inflater never calls getColor on my Resources class for colors defined in my colors.xml (referenced from list_item.xml)

Comment: Very strange: all seems to work fine, the overridden getResources() on my activity is called dozend times during inflate, but not a single call to getColor on the returned CustomResources class.

Comment: @Xnyle Were you able to get this working with your Activity?

Comment: Curious if anyone has success here?