# Overriding resources at runtime

Tags: java, android, android-activity

## The problem

I would like to be able to override my apps resources such as R.colour.brand_colour or R.drawable.ic_action_start at runtime.  My application connects to a CMS system that will provide branding colours and images.  Once the app has downloaded the CMS data it needs to be able to re-skin itself.

I know what you are about to say - overriding resources at runtime is not possible.

Except that it kinda is.  In particular I have found this [Bachelor Thesis](http://comserv.cs.ut.ee/forms/ati_report/downloader.php?file=FE07EAE132DBEEBE7231CEFB0E0200EA2E6E508E) from 2012 which explains the basic concept - The Activity class in android extends `ContextWrapper`, which contains the attachBaseContext method.  You can override attachBaseContext to wrap the Context with your own custom class which overrides methods such as getColor and getDrawable.  Your own implementation of getColor could look the colour up however it wanted.  The [Calligraphy library](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) uses a similar approach to inject a custom LayoutInflator which can deal with loading custom fonts.

## The code

I have created a simple Activity which uses this approach to override the loading of a colour.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(new CmsThemeContextWrapper(newBase));
    }

    private class CmsThemeContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper{

        private Resources resources;

        public CmsThemeContextWrapper(Context base) {
            super(base);
            resources = new Resources(base.getAssets(), base.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(), base.getResources().getConfiguration()){
                @Override
                public void getValue(int id, TypedValue outValue, boolean resolveRefs) throws NotFoundException {
                    Log.i("ThemeTest", "Getting value for resource " + getResourceName(id));
                    super.getValue(id, outValue, resolveRefs);
                    if(id == R.color.theme_colour){
                        outValue.data = Color.GREEN;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public int getColor(int id) throws NotFoundException {
                    Log.i("ThemeTest", "Getting colour for resource " + getResourceName(id));
                    if(id == R.color.theme_colour){
                        return Color.GREEN;
                    }
                    else{
                        return super.getColor(id);
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public Resources getResources() {
            return resources;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, it doesn't work!  The logging shows calls to load resources such as layout/activity_main and mipmap/ic_launcher however color/theme_colour is never loaded.  It seems that the context is being used to create the window and action bar, but not the activity's content view.

My questions is - **Where does the layout inflator load resources from, if not the activities context?**  I would also like to know - **Is there a workable way to override the loading of colours and drawables at runtime?**

## A word about alternative approaches

I know its possible to theme an app from CMS data other ways - for example we could create a method `getCMSColour(String key)` then inside our `onCreate()` we have a bunch of code along the lines of:

```
myTextView.setTextColour(getCMSColour("heading_text_colour"))
```

A similar approach could be taken for drawables, strings, etc.  However this would result in a large amount of boilerplate code - all of which needs maintaining.  When modifying the UI it would be easy to forget to set the colour on a particular view.

Wrapping the Context to return our own custom values is 'cleaner' and less prone to breakage.  I would like to understand why it doesn't work, before exploring alternative approaches.

Comment: Your solution is working: in the activity, if you call getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_colour) result is Color.GREEN as expected. The inflater seems to use another methods to retrieve colors, I don't know which one of them. I tried wrapping application context, but we have the same result...

Comment: Yes, I know calling getResource().getColour() will return green.  However my question, is when the layout is inflated, why aren't the controls I set android:colour="@color/theme_colour" green!

Comment: Not an answer to your question (and indeed, I would be very interested if this was possible) but as another alternative approach, you could override the widgets yourself (TextView, ImageView, etc.) which use your own implementation of "resource provider" (which you've added in your "alternative approach" paragraph and use that inside your views. This way, you reduce the amount of boilerplate code and also it's much easier to maintain themes. At least, that's the approach I would personally take if all else failed instead of overriding the themes and resources in every activity/fragment.

Comment: @kha has a reasonable approach here. Outside of that, there is not a reliable way to dynamically replace values referenced from XML with arbitrary data. Any approach involving reflection _will_ break your app (and we're seeing plenty of this due to resource framework changes in M).

Comment: If Calligraphy is handling this properly, and your code isn't, I'd focus on the differences between how you are registering the `ContextWrapper` and how Chris is.

Comment: @kha - Thanks for your comment.  The approach I have outlined in my question, doesn't make use of any reflection - only subclassing to override public methods.  Are you able to share any information on where the layout inflator is loading resources from - is it not the Activities context?  Why do my overridden  getValue and getColor methods never get called to resolve resources I have referenced in the layout xml?

Comment: @CommonsWare - Thanks.  I am registering the ContextWrapper in the same way Calligraphy does it.  I can confirm that my ContextWrapper is being called, due to the logging statements in getValue and getColor.  Just it never gets called to load resources I have referenced in my layout xml.

Comment: If Calligraphy's `ContextWrapper` works when inflating its layouts, and your `ContextWrapper` does not, then by definition, there is some difference between Calligraphy's `ContextWrapper` and yours. Now, I haven't played with Calligraphy, and it's possible that its `ContextWrapper` fails similar to yours.

Comment: @LukeSleeman My suggestion was to avoid reflection too. I was suggesting something like this: `public class MyTextView extends TextView {
 public MyTextView(Context context, ...) {
  super(context, ...);
  setTextColor(getThemeFromSomewhere(context));
 }
}`. I wrote that here so it's probably all kinds of wrong and quite possibly you want to set the text color somewhere other than the constructor but you see what I mean by sub classing the widgets and using your own versions everywhere in your layout. This way, you can control the themes and you don't have to repeat it in too many places.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Calligraphy is overriding the ContextWrapper to achieve something slightly different - they want to inject their own LayoutInflater, so that once a TextView has been created, they can call setTypeface on it.  This allows Calligraphy to apply custom fonts transparently.  I'm trying to override the loading of resources such as colours, through the ContextWrappers Resource object.

Comment: Ah, I see. My apologies for my prior confusion. In an ideal world, your approach would work. In an ideal world, I'd have hair. It's not an ideal world, more's the pity.

Comment: are you sure, it doesnt work? I tried the snippet above and am seeing the views change to green

Comment: it is true that the context is used to create the window and action bar.. I have couple of back navigtaion on the action bar.. but i am seeing the view change the color based on the getColor/getValue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While "dynamically overriding resources" might seem the straightforward solution to your problem, I believe a cleaner approach would be to use the official data binding implementation https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html since it doesn't imply *hacking* the android way.

You could pass your branding settings using a POJO. Instead of using static styles like `@color/button_color` you could write `@{brandingConfig.buttonColor}` and bind your views with the desired values. With a proper activity hierarchy, it shouldn't add too much boilerplate.

This also gives you the ability to change more complex elements on your layout, i.e.: including different layouts on other layout depending on the branding settings, making your UI highly configurable without too much effort.

Comment: I've just had a play with the data binding library and it does seem to work well for what we need.  About the only thing missing is nice design previews of the databound branding config - eg, doing something like `android:textColor="@{brandingConfig.buttonColor}"` won't result in anything interesting in the visual layout preview in android studio.  This can always be worked around by adding a `tools:` prefixed attribute to set things like strings, drawables, etc for the preview

Comment: After some more thought, I'm marking this as the answer.  You haven't answered the question "Where does the layout inflator load resources from, if not the activities context?".  However you HAVE successfully answered the question "Is there a workable way to override the loading of colours and drawables at runtime?" with a system quite close to what I was trying to achieve.

Also, kudos to you for realising the problem was one of data binding.  Essentially was I was trying to do is get many values from java into the xml layout with the minimum boilerplate.

Answer (score 8):

Having basically the same issue as Luke Sleeman, I had a look at how the `LayoutInflater` is creating the views when parsing the XML layout files. I focused on checking why the string resources assigned to the text attribute of `TextView`s inside the layout are not overwritten by my `Resources` object returned by a custom `ContextWrapper`. At the same time, the strings are overwritten as expected when setting the text or hint programatically through `TextView.setText()` or `TextView.setHint()`.

This is how the text is received as a `CharSequence` inside the constructor of the `TextView` (sdk v 23.0.1):

```
// android.widget.TextView.java, line 973
text = a.getText(attr);
```

where `a` is a `TypedArray` obtained earlier:

```
 // android.widget.TextView.java, line 721
 a = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextView, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
```

The `Theme.obtainStyledAttributes()` method calls a native method on the `AssetManager`:

```
// android.content.res.Resources.java line 1593
public TypedArray obtainStyledAttributes(AttributeSet set,
            @StyleableRes int[] attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr, @StyleRes int defStyleRes) {
...
        AssetManager.applyStyle(mTheme, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes,
                parser != null ? parser.mParseState : 0, attrs, array.mData, array.mIndices);

...
```

And this is the declaration of the `AssetManager.applyStyle()` method:

```
// android.content.res.AssetManager.java, line 746
/*package*/ native static final boolean applyStyle(long theme,
        int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes, long xmlParser,
        int[] inAttrs, int[] outValues, int[] outIndices);
```

In conclusion, even though the `LayoutInflater` is using the correct extended context, when inflating the XML layouts and creating the views, the methods `Resources.getText()` (on the resources returned by the custom `ContextWrapper`) are never called to get the strings for the text attribute, because the constructor of the `TextView` is using the `AssetManager` directly to load the resources for the attributes. The same might be valid for other views and attributes.

Comment: Ahhh - thank you for figuring out the final piece of the puzzle - where the layout inflator loads resources from!  Its unfortunate to see that the approach of wrapping the Context to implement dynamic themes will never work.

Comment: This appears to be the native applyStyle implementation: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/c5d02da0f6553a00da6b0d833b67d3bbe87341e0/libs/androidfw/AttributeResolution.cpp#L205

Answer (score 5):

After searching for a quite long time I finally found an excellent solution.

```
protected void redefineStringResourceId(final String resourceName, final int newId) {
        try {
            final Field field = R.string.class.getDeclaredField(resourceName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(null, newId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Couldn't redefine resource id", e);
        }
    }
```

For a sample test,

```
private Object initialStringValue() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 return getString(R.string.initial_value);
            }
```

And inside the Main activity,

```
before.setText(getString(R.string.before, initialStringValue()));

            final String resourceName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.string.initial_value);
            redefineStringResourceId(resourceName, R.string.evil_value);

            after.setText(getString(R.string.after, initialStringValue()));
```

This solution was originally posted by, **Roman Zhilich**

[ResourceHackActivity](https://github.com/RomanZhilich/android-resource-hack/blob/master/src/tk/dweller/resourcehack/ResourceHackActivity.java)

Comment: Indeed it is possible to use reflection to make fields on the R object point to new resources - the problem is the new resources need to be statically defined in XML as well!  We are interested in colours, strings, drawables, etc that come dynamically from a CMS.  So with your solution you can easily make R.string. initial_value = R.string. evil_value, but you cannot inject a dynamic string from somewhere else.